# Data type of Github User ID

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using Github's API to fetch a user using https://api.github.com/user giving me something like this:

```
{
    "login": "someuser123",
    "id": 1234567,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/...",
    ...
}
```

but what is the data type for the `id` field? I can't seem to find any info on this in the API guides.

Comment: Did either of the answers give you what you needed?

Answer (score 4):

Found a bit of C# in the [Octokit.net codebase](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/Octokit/Models/Response/User.cs) that seems to indicate that User id is a 32-bit integer. From the User constructor (id is buried in the middle of the parameter list):

```cs
public User(string avatarUrl, string bio, string blog, int collaborators, string company, DateTimeOffset createdAt, int diskUsage, string email, int followers, int following, bool? hireable, string htmlUrl, int totalPrivateRepos, int id, string location, string login, string name, int ownedPrivateRepos, Plan plan, int privateGists, int publicGists, int publicRepos, string url, bool siteAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON has a limited set of data types, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example.

As the id is not `null`, `true` or `false` and not in quotes, it is a number. I won't expect decimal points, so it's something like an integer.

Comment: But what kind of number?

Comment: What do you expect? - I assume it to be an integer, but you cannot tell as json does not have something like 32-bit integer or something, you just have number. If you want to know the bits you have to ask the github people!

Comment: Well I'm using Golang and I have to know the data types in advance

Comment: You have two options: Guess a data type which is big enough ask the github people!